# Cap sqlite database size on Android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I am trying to cap the sqlite database size on Android. This is how i am trying to achieve it,

- Call setMaximumSize() on sqlite db object
- Put mDb.replaceOrThrow() within try-catch block so that when the size is full, SQLiteFullException is thrown.
- Catch SQLiteFullException and delete all records in the database. (since i am using the db for caching)

This is what i am observing,

- I get SQLiteException, with error message, "Cannot commit. No transaction is active" after few successful inserts. Higher the set size of the db, more the number of successful transactions before failures.
- I do get SQLiteFullException when i set the maximum size of the db too small to even create the table and so when i call execSQL() with the create table query, it throws SQLiteFullException.

My question is why am i not getting SQLiteFullException during insert/replace? What is the right way to achieve what i am trying?